# sub-algebra of inductive limit(II)

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, c-star-algebras

This question is similar to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032066/sub-algebra-of-inductive-limit), but not the same question.

Let $(A_{i},\alpha_{i})$ be directed system of C* algebras and *-homomorphisms. Let the $\beta_{i}:A_{i}\rightarrow A$ are the canonical *-homomorphisms. Consider some subalgebra $B$ belongs to direct limit $A$. Does it always exists a $j\in I$ such that $B\subseteq \beta_{j}(A_{j})$?

My guess is that is true. Since $A$ is quotient algebra of disjoint union of algebras, we can write every elements $x\in A$ in the form $x=(x_{1},x_{2},...)+N$, with $x_{i}\in A_{i}$, $N$ is the ideal form by equivalence relation. If $B$ is a sub-algebra, then every component of $B$ form a sub-algebra. Is my thought correct?

Comment: The inverse image of a subalgebra under a homomorphism is **always** a subalgebra.

Comment: Yes, I am asking if we do not assume $\beta_{i}$ are surjective, does all subalgebra in $A$ lies in some image of $\beta_{i}$

Comment: Well, this is quite different from asking if $\beta^{-1}_j(B)$ is a subalgebra.   So I guess you should have asked whether $B\subseteq \beta_j(A_j)$, for some $j$.  If this is what you want to know then the answer is no: just take $B$ to be the algebra generated by some element not in the union of the ranges of the $\beta_j$.

Comment: The question you have written is actually weaker than your preveious question. Of course there is a $j$ such that the preimage of $B$ under $\beta_j$ is a subalgebra - this is true for every $j$! If you meant to ask a different question, you should edit to clarify.

Comment: Maybe the confusion is this: the notation $f^{-1}(X)$ makes sense even when $X$ is not contained in the image of $f$.

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope this time is clear

Comment: @Ruy This is what I intend to ask. However I have doubts about the construction you gave. Since $A$ is disjoint union, I think there will be no elements lie outside the union of ranges of $\beta_{j}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inductive limit of C$^*$-algebras is often **not** the union of the ranges of the $\beta _j$.

For instance, consider the
C$^*$-algebra $K$, formed by all compact operators on $\ell ^2$.  Also,  for each $n$,  consider the subset $K_n\subseteq K$, formed by
all  operators whose matrix $(a_{i, j})_{i, j}$, relative to the canonical basis of $\ell ^2$,  have nonzero entries  only in
the top left $n\times n$ block.

Then

- each $K_n$ is a closed $^*$-subalgebra of $K$ (isomorphic to $M_n(\mathbb C)$),
- $K_n\subseteq K_{n+1}$, and
- the union
  $\bigcup_nK_n$ is *dense* in $K$.

With this
much information you are  able to deduce that $K$ is the inductive limit of the $K_n$,  with the connecting maps being
the inclusions $K_n\hookrightarrow K_{n+1}$.

Observing that every operator in $\bigcup_nK_n$ has finite rank, we see that $\bigcup_nK_n$ is not equal to $K$.   It
is only a dense $^*$-subalgebra (and hence can't be the inductive limit in the category of C$^*$-algebras since we want the
inductive limit to be a C$^*$-algebra).

Any
infinite rank compact operator  will therefore  generate a subalgebra that is not contained in the union of the ranges
of the $\beta _j$.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I would like to ask if we require $B$ to be dense also, will the answer changes?

Comment: No, the answer will still be negative.  In fact the worst case is when $B$ is the whole inductive limit!